# Worksheet reference not working in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

This line of code does not work in excel 2013 no  matter I do. wsCheck is simply referencing a worksheet:

```
wsCheck.Range("XEK2:XEK" & SG2Count).Sort Key1:=wsCheck.Columns("XEK"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, SortMethod:=xlPinYin, Header:=xlYes
```

This ran perfectly in 2010 Excel and it was in a lot of my macros and now it simply does not work with the addition of:

```
 SortMethod:=xlPinYin, Header:=xlYes
```

and if not added simply sorts in the header. I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. I am hoping to get a good explanation as to why this method does not work across 2010 vs 2013 and what needs to be added in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2013 is doing what you tell it and sorting just the range you specify, whereas it seems that Excel 2010 automatically expanded the range to adjacent cells (I don't have access to Excel 2010 at the moment).

You can force Excel to expand the range by using the **CurrentRegion** property as :

`wsCheck.Range("XEK2:XEK" & SG2Count).CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=wsCheck.Columns("XEK"), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, SortMethod:=xlPinYin, Header:=xlYes`